# Counting holes in a Bitmap

Tags: algorithm, math, matrix, graphics, bitmap

Hello I am having an issues with these two matrix and fully understanding the problem. I understand the rule is that a hole is when there is a connected group of 0s in one or more of four directions: up, down, left, or right. But the issues is with the answer to these matrix

This one is 3, but to my understanding I am getting 2

```
0 1 1 1 1
0 1 1 0 1
0 0 0 1 1
1 1 1 1 0
```

This one below here is 2, to my understanding I agree with

```
1 0 1 1
0 0 1 0
```

So in all, why is it that the first one results in 3?

Comment: Are you certain the definition is **"one or more"** of each direction? It's simple to see what's happening if it's just one of each direction.

Answer (score 1):

Diagonal is NOT up, down, left or right.  So the 0 in the upper right is an hole all by itself and not part of the group of 5 near it.

Comment: alright thanks, makes sense now I interpreted the problem wrong in my head, I though a hole was a combination of more than one zero. Thank you